# Apple Music on Apple TV 3?

Tags: appletv, apple-music

Is it possible to get Apple Music on Apple TV 3? I can stream to it from my iMac, but it would be nice to be able to launch Apple Music from TV directly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, previous versions of the AppleTV do not support the new Apple Music service.   In order to use the service with AppleTV, you'll need to either 1) stream from a compatible device, such as an iPhone / iPad / Mac, or 2) upgrade to the latest 4th generation AppleTV.

Answer (score 0):

Just stream Apple Music from your iPhone or iPad to the Apple TV via AirPlay.

Answer (score -1):

no hifi, in apple tv4 only hdmi for movie, no hifi...

Only with apple tv 3 that you could hook it up to a decent DAC to have hifi.

it is a shame apple didn't care about apple tv3 and allowing music on it.

And worst of all, when you start subscribing to music, Apple unplug the imatch fonction, so your apple tv, is useless.

Answer (score -3):

I may be possible o use Apple Music on the 3rd generation Apple TV.  I expect that you would have to get an 4th generation Apple TV, hack it to access the files for the Music app, then hack the 3rd gen Apple TV to install the Music app.  Then hack it some more to get it to run the Music app.  Might I suggest that with less effort you could save the money to upgrade to the 4th generation Apple TV in a few months.  Patience.